# How to modify partially and build .net-framework source-code provided by microsoft and use alongside existing project

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, workflow-foundation

Microsoft has open sourced part of it's .net framework [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource), i'm using window workflow foundation and need to expand it and add some properties to [this sealed class (FlowDecision)](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Activities/System/Activities/Statements/FlowDecision.cs).

How i can  build the modified .net-framework and use its changed class mentioned above in one of existing projects.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by adding properties to FlowDecision? It's likely that there's an easier solution to that problem.

Comment: i'm trying to make a human-intractable flow decision. i have overrided the default designer for declension i want to add an 'approver' property to the flowdecision and pass it it the condition activity the sort out some approve/reject activity with two output paths.

Comment: You can't roll your own out of a `FlowSwitch<T>`?

Comment: it's also sealed and methods are internal

Comment: Not a subclass of `FlowSwitch<T>`. An instance. Why is there a requirement for the approver to be a public property of the node itself, rather than just something the `Expression` delegate has access to?

Comment: Actually i want to add more variables to the `flowdecision` and bind them from `activity designer`